# Add MM-DD to Year Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains birth years:

```
Name     Birth Year
Joe         2000
Bill        1998
Mike        1996
Frank       1995
```

I want to add a column called "DOB" that adds the same MM-DD to the Birth year so that the DataFrame looks like:

```
Name     Birth Year     DOB
Joe         2000       2000-04-13
Bill        1998       1998-04-13
Mike        1996       1996-04-13
Frank       1995       1995-04-13
```

Incorrectly, this is my attempt at doing this:

```
df['DOB'] = str(df['Birth Year'] + '-' + '04-13').dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: Do you want datetime like results or strings?

Comment: datimetime results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), if you want the column to be of type `DateTime`:

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birth_Year'].astype(str) + '-04-13', format='%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Name  Birth_Year        DOB
0    Joe        2000 2000-04-13
1   Bill        1998 1998-04-13
2   Mike        1996 1996-04-13
3  Frank        1995 1995-04-13
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```py
df['DOB'] = df['Birth Year'].astype(str) + "-04-13"
```

the issue you had is that 'Birth Year' column is probably a number and not a string

Comment: This works; however, I need to have the it formatted with to_datetime

Answer (score 1):

#### `pandas.to_datetime`

Can take a dataframe with appropriately named columns.  The minimum columns needed are `['Year', 'Month', 'Day']`

```
dates = pd.DataFrame({'Year': df['Birth Year'], 'Month': 4, 'Day': 13})
df.assign(DOB=pd.to_datetime(dates))

    Name  Birth Year        DOB
0    Joe        2000 2000-04-13
1   Bill        1998 1998-04-13
2   Mike        1996 1996-04-13
3  Frank        1995 1995-04-13
```

To see what `dates` looks like

```
dates

   Year  Month  Day
0  2000      4   13
1  1998      4   13
2  1996      4   13
3  1995      4   13
```